# Find and Replace with RegEx in Sublime Text

Tags: regex, replace, sass, sublimetext

I use sass mixin and i want change my old code using regex 
for example i have the next scss code

```
margin-left:30px;
margin-right:3em;
padding-right:1rem;
```

to

```
@include margin-start(30px);
@include margin-end(3em);
@include padding-end(1rem);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i find solution :

```
Find: (margin-right:)\s(\-|((.*){1,3}))(\;$)
Replace: @include margin-end(\3)

Find: (margin-left:)\s(\-|((.*){1,3}))(\;$)
Replace: @include margin-start(\3)

Find: (padding-right:)\s(\-|((.*){1,3}))(\;$)
Replace: @include padding-end(\3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex:

```
(\w+\-\w+:\w+;)
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/hO2sO3/1)**

**Match information**

```
MATCH 1
1.  [0-17]  `margin-left:30px;`
MATCH 2
1.  [18-35] `margin-right:3em;`
MATCH 3
1.  [36-55] `padding-right:1rem;`
```

**SUBSTITUTION**

```
@include margin-left:30px;
@include margin-right:3em;
@include padding-right:1rem;
```

Comment: but with this method it'll select padding-top:1rem; this is not what i need